# Preferred strategy for git pull with permanent local changes

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I cloned a remote repository and changed one file. Now I want to update the repository from remote time-to-time, but keep the changes in that file. I could find several strategies all over the internet:

- commit the file to master and rebase on every git pull (i.e. git fetch && git merge --ff-only)
- commit the file to a different branch and cherry-pick on every git pull
- commit the file to a fork and update the remote fork from the original remote
- stash file before and stash pop after every git pull
- create patch file and patch the file on every git pull
- maintain external older copy, remove the conflicting file before git pull and merge changes using external merge tool after git pull
- --assume-unchanged & --skip-worktree (it seems these don't work the way I want, but are recommended all over the stackoverflow)
- modifying .git directory (does it worth the effort to poke around in .git folder and possibly break something, even though this is only a local clone of a remote?)

There could be posssibly some other approaches.

What is the preferred strategy for git pull with permanent local changes? Are there any limitations with any of these? What is the most safe approach in terms of preserving most of the remote and local changes and avoiding merge conflicts?

Comment: You can’t avoid merge conflicts if you both edit a file, but you can tell git whose changes to prefer. To me it sounds like you want to “pull rebase”.

Comment: I know I can't, but some methods could be more conflict-proof than others (i.e. patch file might cause much more conflicts than git rebase). I don't have much experience, I still use the 6th way (which is probably the worst). I don't even know what is the common solution to this problem as I could not find any documentation about this topic.

Comment: Don’t be afraid of conflicts. They’re expected if you and someone else are both changing a file. No solution will always be bulletproof.

Comment: I'm not, I'm just looking for a better approach than what I use currently

Comment: Which approach do you currently use? Do you use branches? Are they long lived branches or short feature branches? Do you share your branch? Do others use your branch?

Comment: The 6th approach/bullet in my question. I'm the only user of my local copy, anyway the remote is obviously shared with coworkers.

Comment: I personally just merge master into my local branch (after a pull obviously) and handle any conflicts (which there normally aren’t).